# How to compare two iterators in scala?

Tags: scala, iterator, comparison

For now, I have only 3 way to compare two iterators (with String type) in scala:

```
// 1.
it1 sameElements it2

// 2.
it2.toList == it2.toList

// 3. 
def compare(it1:Iterator[String], it2:Iterator[String]) {
  while (it1.hasNext) {
    if (!it2.hasNext) return false
    if (it1.next != it2.next) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return !it2.hasNext
}
```

Is there any other good ways to do this?

Comment: Why not use your first way, `sameElements`? I suppose the reason this isn't just called `==` is because it's (necessarily) side-effecting, emptying the iterators.

Comment: If you explained what's wrong with these, it would help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, I just want to know as more solutions as possible, for learning scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use zip:

```
def compare(it1:Iterator[String], it2:Iterator[String]) = {
  it1.zip(it2).forall(x => x._1 == x._2) && 
  (it1.length == it2.length)    
}
```

Or you can also use tail recursion:

```
def compare(it1:Iterator[String], it2:Iterator[String]) : Boolean = {
  (it1 hasNext, it2 hasNext) match{
    case (true, true) => (it1.next == it2.next) && compare(it1, it2)
    case (false, false) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

The function used for `sameElements`, which I recommend as it is used in the API, I modified the [source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1013) signature for readability

```
def compare(it1:Iterator[String], it2:Iterator[String]) = {
  while (it1.hasNext && it2.hasNext)
    if (it1.next != it2.next) return false
  !it1.hasNext && !it2.hasNext
}
```

Comment: I think the first `compare` has some issues. Calling `.length` will empty the iterator.

Comment: There are some compilation errors, I've fixed the last two, but I don't know how to fix the first: `wrong number of parameters; expected = 1`

Comment: So we can do it in the other order, I will edit my post. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: For first method I corrected it, it didn't like the fact that there were 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use [canEqual](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/util/Try.html#canEqual(that:Any):Boolean) :

```
@annotation.tailrec
def compare(it1:Iterator[String], it2:Iterator[String]) : Boolean = {
  Try(it1.next()).canEqual(Try(it2.next())) && compare(it1, it2)
}
```